# Classification of quartic surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, rational-points

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero (non necessarily algebraically closed, we may assume for instance that $k = \mathbb{C}(t)$). Does there exist a classification of degree four surfaces $S\subset\mathbb{P}^3_{k}$ (defined over $k$) up to the action of $PGL(4,k)$ or of the Cremona group of $\mathbb{P}^3_{k}$?

Thank you.

Comment: By the adjunction formula these are K3 surfaces, so you might want to look at the literature on them.

Comment: I do not think they are $K3$ in general. For instance, a quartic surface with a double line is not $K3$.

Answer (score 2):

A fine classification of the quartic surfaces that are not normal is in

Tohsuke URABE, "Classification of Non-normal Quartic Surfaces", TOKYO J. MATH. VOL. 9, No. 2, 1986, 265-295

Comment: Yes, I know this paper but I think this classification works just when the base field is algebraically closed.